# Android: Grabbing app meta data

Tags: java, android

Ok, here is what I am interested in doing:

On apps that I have installed, I am interested in knowing if I can programmatically search the app store for that apps meta data (application type, category, content rating, etc).  So my app would see that a user has Chrome installed and would look in the play store, grab the meta data and then I can use that for whatever.

I have looked at rather great lengths to see if this is possible over at http://developer.android.com but haven't seen anything that looks like what I'm looking to do.  Any pointer in the right direction would be immensely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts of this.  First is getting the packages of all installed apps.

```
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final List pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
```

Second is scraping metadata from the Google play store.  This isn't hard if you can do the step above.  All apps are available at the URL:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package>
```

So for example, the Chrome app is at:  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome

You can use an [XPath parser](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) and pull out specific fields from this data, so long as Google doesn't change the layout of the page.

Alternately there is an [Unofficial API](https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/) for getting play store metadata that might be easier.

Comment: Yeah, I have the list of apps without a problem.  Unfortunate I have to scrape a website to do this and hope the play store doesn't change.  That solution really isn't too difficult.  I was hoping for a nice little avenue to query the play store by package name and get an object back that has something similar to what I want.

Comment: Then check out the Unofficial API that I linked.  It does that for you.

Comment: Cool, I'll look at this and when it works, I'll accept this as an answer.  Thanks for the help!